# How can I fix the styling of my li element so it appears on same line?

Tags: html, css

How do I make the words stay on same line?:

[image]

This is my cshtml - they share the same class.

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Reservations" asp-action="Index">Reservations</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <span class="nav-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
</li>
```

Comment: I don't think this is related to either ASP.NET Core or Razor, as this is a CSS issue. Please remove the ASP.NET Core and Razor tags.

Comment: Also, could you share the style sheet used for this portion of your application? Specifically, the ul, li and nav-item portion.

Comment: try to change  class nav-text to nav-link

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap4, then you should read this [Navbar, Text](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#text)

Answer (score 0):

align-self will help to make text center of its height.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

li.nav-item {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Reservations" asp-action="Index">Reservations</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <span class="nav-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
  </li>

</ul>
```